# Does Office 365's Excel for Web Support Event Listeners?

Tags: excel, office365, office-scripts

I was taking a look at the [ExcelScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript?view=office-scripts) but unless I missed something I have the feeling that *Event Listeners* are not currently implemented in Office Scripts (TypeScript/ExcelScript) for Office 365's Excel for Web...

Essentially, I want to add an Event Listener to a Worksheet [ex. onChange.add()] so I can lock the active cell after any data has been inputted...

Are Event Listeners even available?

I'm not looking for anyone to write any code just a **Yes** or **No** answer to whether or not *Event Listeners* are implemented, and if Yes, a little nudge to the applicable API documentation.

Much appreciated <3

Comment: Correct, it doesn't currently exist.

Comment: @Skin, why not add your comment as an Answer?

Comment: Because it's a weak answer.  You know you could always use PowerAutomate/LogicApps to catch the change of the workbook and then apply your logic that way.  It won't be instantaneous though.

Comment: @Skin, Fair enough and appreciate the alternative, thank you.